# Youtube API : Uploading the video more than once over YouTube (via api) doesn't provide any exception

Tags: php, youtube-api

Uploading the video more than once over YouTube (via api) doesn't provide any exception. Instead it returns the success in response.

YouTube response after uploading same video is given in this link:

https://bpaste.net/raw/5504d0129088

Comment: And?  they will both have two different ids YouTube doesn't check that you are uploading the same video it assumes you are smart enough to check that it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

> [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) 
>  Uploads a video to YouTube and optionally sets
> the video's metadata.

All it does is insert a video. It does not check that a video with that name or metadata or file doesn't already exist.  That is the developers job.   You can keep uploading the same video as many times as you like it will get a different id and YouTube will treat it as a different video.

In this instance you would only see an exception if the file did not upload correctly.   The fact that you are not seeing an exception is as it should be.